# Generating report dynamically using ASP.NET AJAX

Tags: asp.net, ajax, gridview

I've googled this to death and can't find anything that points me in the right direction so any help would be much appreciated!

I want to generate a report that consists of X no. of gridviews (X can vary) where each gridview is added one at a time using ajax (to avoid timeout of rendering all gridviews in single post back).  I am also hoping that when rendering the next gridview a progress bar/timer can also appear in it's place until it's finished processing and is rendered.

Does anyone know how I might tackle this? I wouldn't have a problem doing this in a single post back but now the reports are timing out I need to generate the report piece by piece dynamically.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do they have to be gridviews? i don't know much about gridview but you could do something like this fairly easily by generating simple html tables clientside.

Comment: Thanks for the response. They are a kind of gridview, we have our own server controls that basically do the same thing but all the html is generated in the class. I only said gridview so people can relate easier.  Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you divide the page into different sections and load each section individually.

Are your gridviews interdependent..?

Comment: That sounds very similar to an idea I had yesterday evening but not sure if it's practical.

The gridviews are independent so I will want each individual gridview to page, sort and work independently from the rest of the page.

If I knew I was dealing with X no. of gridviews I could create X no. of iframes on my main page and within each iframe I could load a singe gridview.  This would mean I could re-use the same page for each iframe.

I'm just trying to come with a more efficient way of generating my reports instead of the usual single post back which is timing out.

Comment: Why not add Separate Panels containing GridView and each Panel will show loading image till the GridView is loaded with your data.

Comment: I assume you mean the ajax updatepanel? if so, since the no. of  gridviews needed can vary, how can I dynamically add these to the page using ajax/clientscript where as you suggest, each one generates it's own gridview? 

Scenario being: Report page has loaded, I configure the parameters and then click create report.  Below, depending on the parameters selected it will generate x no. of gridviews in sequence (each on loading indepedent on one another).

Am I talking nonsense?